# Selenium switch to frame not working for Chrome 58

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

After I've updated my Chrome to version 58, I cannot switch to the frame. 
Here is my code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(frameId);
```

Tried to use another two overloaded **frame()** methods (that accepts *index* and *WebElement*) - the same problem.

Here is the exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: no such frame: element is not a frame
    (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 20 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
    System info: host: 'slava', ip: '192.168.2.9', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b), userDataDir=C:\Users\SlavaM\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir528_2137}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.110, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
    Session ID: 14cb3f8dc100a369d4c99453b44cfe21

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.frame(RemoteWebDriver.java:937)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.frame(RemoteWebDriver.java:932)
    at com.privowny.selenium.base.BaseTest.switchToFrame(BaseTest.java:251)
    at com.privowny.selenium.base.BaseTest.openPasswordManagerSection(BaseTest.java:439)
    at com.privowny.selenium.base.BaseTest.openPasswordListInPasswordManager(BaseTest.java:343)
    at com.privowny.selenium.password.PasswordScoreTest.testPasswordsScoreRate(PasswordScoreTest.java:48)
    at com.privowny.selenium.password.PasswordScoreTest.scoreTest(PasswordScoreTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
```

For Chrome 57, 56 and older everything works fine. Any ideas?

---

UPD: Here is real html. As we can see, there is no iframe's content there:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test page</title>
</head>
<div id="testBarBlock"
     style="position: fixed; margin: -145.5px 0px 0px; overflow: visible; z-index: 2147483647; top: 50%; right: 0px; width: 60px; display: block;">
    <div id="testHeaderBar"
         style="position: absolute; width: 38px; height: 50px; background: rgb(52, 55, 56); padding: 0px 6px; right: 0px;">
        <div id="testHeaderBarNav"
             style="position: relative; height: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);">
            <div id="PBIframeHolderDraggable"
                 style="position: absolute; top: 5px; width: 10px; height: 10px; cursor: move; background-image: url(&quot;chrome-extension://gfhgplpdgglgiaafgmfhjabegdctest/app/images/bar/points.png&quot;); background-size: cover; left: 0px;"></div>
            <span id="testCollapseBar"
                  style="position: absolute; top: 5px; width: 10px; height: 10px; cursor: pointer; background-size: cover; background-image: url(&quot;chrome-extension://gfhgplpdgglgiaafgmfhjabegdctest/app/images/bar/arrowRight.png&quot;); right: 0px;"></span><span
                id="testExtendBar"
                style="position: absolute; top: 5px; width: 10px; height: 10px; cursor: pointer; background-size: cover; display: none; background-image: url(&quot;chrome-extension://gfhgplpdgglgiaafgmfhjabegdctest/app/images/bar/arrowLeft.png&quot;); right: 0px;"></span>
        </div>
        <img src="chrome-extension://gfhgplpdgglgiaafgmfhjabegdctest/app/images/logo.png" id="testLogo"
             style="display: block; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; top: 22px; left: 10px; width: 27px; height: 27px; background: none; position: absolute; box-shadow: none;">
    </div>
    <div id="testIframeHolder"
         style="width: 80px; height: 291px; position: absolute; overflow: visible; top: 50px;">
        <iframe id="testIframeBar" name="barRightExpand" frameborder="0"
                src="chrome-extension://gfhgplpdgglgiaafgmfhjabegdctest/app/modules/core/view/bar/bar.html"
                style="width: 80px; height: 291px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 2147483647; left: auto;"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<body class="beautify">
<div class="ui-editor"><textarea class="ui-field json testIconExist" id="editor" spellcheck="false"
                                 contenteditable="true">{"ID":null,"name":"Doe","first-name":"John","age":25,"hobbies":["reading","cinema",{"sports":["volley-ball","badminton"]}],"address":{}}</textarea><span
        class="testActionIcon iconForInput" elemleft="0.00" elemtop="0.00"
        style="width: 19px; height: 19px; left: 932px; top: 497.5px;"><img
        src="chrome-extension://gfhgplpdgglgiaafgmfhjabegdctest/app/images/logo_up_primary.png"
        class="imgtestActionIcon"></span>
    <div class="ui-resizer"></div>
</div>
<div class="ui-aside">
    <div class="ui-notification" id="status"></div>
    <div class="ui-menu">
        <div class="ui-menu-dropdown">
            <div class="ui-menu-panel">
                <div class="ui-menu-item ui-option" id="beautify">Beautify</div>
                <div class="ui-menu-item ui-option" id="show-types">Show Types</div>
                <div class="ui-menu-item ui-option" id="show-indexes">Show Indexes</div>
                <div class="ui-menu-item about" style="display:none">About</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML that is in the iframe is loading from my extension. It is well displayed on the UI, works fine but when I inspect element - no content there. Just checked on Chrome 57 - I can see the content there.

So this is a problem, and I understand why selenium is throwing me this error.

Now the question is why Google Chrome decided to hide iframe's content from me and how can I test my iframe using selenium. Funny is that I can see the html of another iframe that is loaded from external resource (not from the extension).

Comment: Please share the part of your code where you are assigning frameId and also the HTML code from where you are getting the frame's ID.  I realize you're saying it worked in an earlier version, but the error says that the element is not a frame.  Seeing both of those might shed a clue.

Comment: @BillHileman Just updated the question. Hope it will help.

Comment: @BillHileman Ha.. when I click "Inspect" on the iframe, Chrome opens me another "Developer tool" window with the content of iframe. Why did they do it and how can I test my code with selenium now..

Comment: Go to the same page on firefox.  There are various add-ons (plug-ins?) like firebug, firepath, etc., that you will find much better to determine your xpaths.

Comment: I'm testing the extension and my selenium tests are written only for Chrome. I can not go with Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK,It's caused by the [OOPIF](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/oop-iframes).
Simply put,the iframe with different origin will be rendered in different process.

- You can reproduce this issue in chrome 57 by enabling #enable-site-per-process in chrome://flags.
- You can also reference [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1366&q=no%20such%20frame&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary).

Comment: Seems like this is the problem. But when I changed flag #enable-site-per-process on v58 - nothing changed - iframe's content still not loaded. Don't you know how can I make my extension's iframes to be loaded in the same process as the page?

Comment: @viachm The new chrome driver fix this bug.
See https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.30/notes.txt

Comment: Yes, you're right. The problem is fixed with the new driver v2.30

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`driver.switchTo().frame("barRightExpand");`

If it is not working share here full html-code.

Comment: I suspect that the problem here related to the thing that Chrome 58 is no longer shows you in the devltool iframe's content in case when this iframe is loaded from the extension.

Comment: You have no element `frame`, you have element `iframe`. Try to change in your training code tag `iframe` on tag `frame` run the test and look at what is result.