# Cannot change text in input field - input element is not found, but it exists

Tags: angular, selenium, robotframework

I'm testing a web service with Selenium. Some elements on a page are modified by Angular. I'm trying to change text in an input field but when I check the source code it is not an `input` but a `span` element which is non-editable.

For example, on https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_form (not the page I'm testing but shows exactly the same problem) we have some input elements:

```
<form novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched"><br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastName" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty">
    <br><br>
    <button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
</form>
```

It is not really hard to write xpath for such an element but what surprised me was that Selenium couldn't find any `inputs` on the page.

```
ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=//input' did not match any elements.
```

So I used [Log Source](https://rickypc.github.io/robotframework-extendedselenium2library/doc/ExtendedSelenium2Library.html#Log%20Source) keyword from ExtendedSelenium2Library to verify it, and in logged source code the `input` element that I'm interested in looked like this:

```
<span class="cm-m-xml cm-tag">input</span>
```

so this is actually a `span`.

Firstly I thought Angular has something in common with this behaviour and I tried to locate the element by some specific Angular locators like:

```
input text  model=user.firstName  Hello!
```

and it always ends up with

```
ValueError: Element locator 'model=user.firstName' did not match any elements
```

So I wrote xpath for `span` element. It was found but finally ends up with:

```
InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.
```

My last code looks like this (this is only testing code):

```
*** Settings ***
#Library         Selenium2Library
#Library         AngularJSLibrary
Library          ExtendedSelenium2Library
Test Setup  open browser  url=${url}  browser=chrome
Test Teardown  close browser


*** Variables ***
${url}  https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_form


*** Test Cases ***
Will change it?
  #  Go to  ${url}
  #  Wait for angular
  #  input text  model=user.firstName  Hello!
     Log Source
     input text  xpath=//span[@class="cm-m-javascript cm-string" and text()='"John"']  Hello!
```

I tried Selenium2Library, AngularJSLibrary, ExtendedSelenium2Library and a lot of xpath expressions, with no success.

To make long question short: based on this [example page](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_form),
how to change the value of First Name input field with Robot Framework Selenium?

Part of my `pip freeze`:

```
robotframework==3.0.2
robotframework-angularjs==0.0.6
robotframework-extendedselenium2library==0.9.1
robotframework-selenium2library==1.8.0
```

I'm using Python 2.7.13.

Comment: On your linked example page, `//input` returns six matches and `//input[@ng-model='user.firstName']` matches the first name input element.

Comment: @BillHileman Could you please share with me versions of libraries you're using? Maybe I have some versions problems.

Comment: I was going solely by Chrome developer tools, sorry.  I was only validating the xpath access, nothing more.

Comment: That's right when I'm parsing page source code in web console with //input xpath it shows 6 elements, but with ExtendedSelenium2Library it didn't match any.

Comment: Then I think you're on the right path in that it almost has to be a selenium libraries issue.  I don't work with angular or python, so I'm afraid I can't be any more help.

Comment: This isn't an Angular issue. Using Selenium, I'm able to enter text into the inputs on that example page. Can you share any of your code? Or the actual URL of the page you're testing?

Comment: Hi @Ian actually I cant share with the page and the exact code, this is the issue I faced at work, that's why I use example page with the same problems. Could you please share how you entered the text to input on this example page with Robot Framework Selenium? and versions of libraries which you use?

Comment: Can you anonymize the snippet of your test code? And by any chance, is your form inside of an iframe (as it is on the example page)?

Comment: Also, can you update to include the entire source logged by Log Source?

Comment: Hi @Ian sorry for lack of information. The mentioned web service was unavailable yesterday, I will back to it today and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ian comment and help of my manager at work I finally handled the issue.

First thing I wasn't aware that iframes are so special. If someone want to read something about them [here](https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html) is good article.

So I tried to select proper frame with [Select Frame](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20Frame) keyword but I encountered a problem with selecting it in chrome and ends up with

```
NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame: element is not a frame
```

but I found that chrome I use have some [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918954/selenium-switch-to-frame-not-working-for-chrome-58) with proper frames detection.

So I tried with FF with following results: for FF version 58 I've got timeout exception during the browser open

```
Setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: timeouts
```

so I downgraded it to FF version 55 and got an error at Select Frame call

```
NoSuchFrameException: Message: Unable to locate frame
```

so I downgrade it again to version 53 and got problem with sending keys:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Expected [object Undefined] undefined
```

[link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/659) to description. And finally downgrade it to version 52 and code below starts working:

```
*** Settings ***
Library          SeleniumLibrary
Test Setup  open browser  ${url}
Test Teardown  close browser


*** Variables ***
${url}  https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_form


*** Test Cases ***
Will change it?
    Log Source  # for debug
    Select frame  iframeResult  
    Log Source  # for debug
    Input Text   xpath=//input  Hello!
```

I found as well that [Selenium2Library](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html) I'm using is legacy and change it to [SeleniumLibrary](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary)

This are my final libraries versions:

```
robotframework==3.0.2
robotframework-angularjs==0.0.6
robotframework-extendedselenium2library==0.9.1
robotframework-selenium2library==1.8.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.1.1
```

at the end I upgraded my chrome to version 64.0.3282.186 (I should probably start with that) and code presented above works perfectly. For the target web service as well ;)

Thanks everyone who tried help!